# Matching a specific url in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match youtube and vimeo urls on javascript. I'm using regexr to play around and came up with this:

```
(http|https)://(youtu|www.youtube|vimeo|youtube)\.(be|com)/[A-Za-z0-9\?&=]+
```

It works pretty well on regexr, whitespaces aren't included in the match so it would only match this:

```
http://youtu.be/ssdfsjlfsfsl
```

And not this:

```
http://youtu.be/ssdfsjl someword
```

But when I test it out on javascript it still matches the url with a whitespace and another word beside it:

```
var x = new RegExp("(http|https)://(youtu|www.youtube|vimeo|youtube)\.(be|com)/[A-Za-z0-9\?&=]+")

x.test("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvYo3ZgaQ1c&feature=plcp someword")
```

Not sure why this is happening, I've also tried adding `\S` or `!\s` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Wouldn't that *also* allow the domain and tld of `vimeo.be` (this *may* exist, but it's not one I've come across).

Comment: oops, thanks for telling me that, I guess it still needs some fixing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regex.test(string)` returns a boolean value of whether one or more matches are found in the string, so it would (and should) return `true` for `"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvYo3ZgaQ1c&feature=plcp someword"`.

If you want to test that your string is a URL and ONLY a url, add some anchors:

```
^(http|https)://(youtu|www.youtube|vimeo|youtube)\.(be|com)/[A-Za-z0-9\?&=]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like you're checking for the start / end of the string. Using `^` and `$`

```
var x = new RegExp("^(http|https)://(youtu|www.youtube|vimeo|youtube)\.(be|com)/[A-Za-z0-9\?&=]+$")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you haven't anchored your expression.

```
^(http|https)://(youtu|www.youtube|vimeo|youtube)\.(be|com)/[A-Za-z0-9\?&=]+$
|                                                                           |
here, and...                                                                here.
```